# MySQL multiple redirect output to files lead to inconsistent output in files

Tags: mysql

I am using two command line redirects for MySQL:

First redirect:

```
mysql -vN --show-warnings  -u${USER} -p${PASSWORD} -h ${HOST} dbname -se " select something" > ${SQL_OUT_FILE}
```

Second redirect:

```
mysql -vN --show-warnings  -u${USER} -p${PASSWORD} -h ${HOST} dbname -se " select anotherthing" > ${OUT_FILE_2}
```

Now the file OUT_FILE_2 contains the "select something" as a value.

I am not sure why the select query that got executed in the first redirect would be present in the second out file.

I am leaning to the theory that there is some command line cache which is pushing the last sql query executed into the second out file.

It would be great if someone can point to a resource which explains the above behavior.